# UITableViewCell not moving up and down

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hello all does anyone know if it's possible or that the UITableviewcells have a function or attribute that allows them to not move up or down( when you scroll with the mouse)
Just as if it where a couple of buttons glued to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke too soon ;)
figured it out

`[[self tableView] setScrollEnabled:NO]`